# MySQL Массовое Обновление и запись базу данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Столкнулся с задачей, есть две переменные

```
$start = 015223; //начальное значение
```

и

```
$finish = 628311; //конечное значение
```

цифры всегда шестизначные и могут быть произвольными но `start` всегда меньше чем `finish` в базе данных в таблице есть два столбца `id` и `number`

- id идентификатор с атрибутом автоинкремент
- number хранят шестизначные числа

Задача такова занести в базу данных числовой промежуток между `start` и `finish`, но так что бы если в базе уже есть строка с совпадающим числом, оно не записывалось повторно.

Я конечно могу настроить громоздкую конструкцию из цикла `for` в котором будет сначала производиться выборка `SELECT` и проверка на количество выбранных столбцов, и в случае если `num_rows` возвращает 0 то делать `INSERT` но как понимаете это просто супер ресурсозатратно будет и громозко - может есть какая то упрощающая функция вроде как `DISTINCT` при выборке что бы все упростить??

Comment: Какой диалект? `generate_series` в `postgresql` и псевдотаблицы `ha_sequence` в `mariadb` 10+ помогут желаемое сделать одним не очень сложным запросом.

Comment: @Мелкий да пожалуйста главное что бы было лучше моей придумки с for

Comment: Дык какой диалект? Мне не улыбается просто так расписывать все возможные диалекты.

Comment: @Мелкий ой я в этом слаб даже не знаю как определить диалект, вобщем у меня денвер на нем mysql 5.5 настроен phpmyadmin я сайт делаю - по этому можно определить диалект??

Comment: Да, диалект `mysql`. Тупой как пробка, ничего полезного не умеет. Сейчас подумаю и чего-нибудь напишу ответом, как можно сделать задачу менее болезненным образом...

Comment: @Мелкий а есть другие в вебе контачат с php? еслид а то посоветуйте буду раскуривать

Comment: Пользуйся  insert ignore into test_warnings (id_, num_) values (?,?)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как выяснили в комментариях, речь о `mysql 5.5`. Никаких полезных `generate_series` или эквивалентов не умеет, так что надо извращаться.

### Варианты не очень правильные

Шестизначные числа, значит максимум 1 млн записей - это на самом деле не слишком дофига. Можно вычитать из таблицы всё по `where number between :start and :end` в простой массив `number => true`, займет сколько-то мегабайт памяти в худшем случае. Затем в `for` с помощью `isset` проверять, надо ли такое число в списке, если нет - то накапливать в отдельный массив и каждые, этак, 1000 элементов сбрасывать в одним запросом в базу. Не слишком правильная мысль, но можно.

Можно ровно так же делать, но вычитывать не всё, а разбив исходный диапазон на несколько блоков, например, по 50 тыс чисел - для полного обхода потребуется 20 запросов к базе на чтение.

Или всё тот же способ, но ещё один вариант, позволяющий контролировать и расход памяти в худшем случае и минимальное число запросов в лучшем: вычитывать в массив `where number >= :start order by number limit 10000`. Если вам вернулось меньше чем `limit` записей - действуете по первому сценарию, вы вычитали все используемые числа, все остальные от start до end вам нужно добавить в базу. Если вернулось ровно то число записей, что указано в limit - то, возможно, у вас есть ещё данные в таблице. Тогда вы запоминаете последний number из результата запроса, и когда ваш for дошёл до этого числа - делаете ещё запрос к базе подставив ваш последнее встреченное число `where number >= :last_number order by number limit 10000` и пересоздаёте ваш массив с имеющимися id в базе. Это будет хорошо работать, если обычно в вашей таблице немного записей и пропуски встречаются часто.

### Снова варианты

Более странные, но более производительные. Если требуется такую задачу выполнять более-менее часто, то создайте таблицу, например:

```
create table int_series (number int(11) unsigned not null primary key);
```

Любым возможным способом запишите в неё последовательно числа от 1 до 999999. И больше её не трогайте, она не для того сделана, чтобы её как-то трогать, кроме как читать. Теперь вся ваша задача сводится к вызову запроса:

```
insert into `tablename` (number)
select number 
    from int_series
    left join tablename using(number)
    where tablename.number is null
        and number between :start and :end
```

Это всё. Серьёзно.

Для Postgresql, о котором упоминал в комментариях, просто не нужна эта лишняя таблица, можно сразу сделать:

```
insert into `tablename` (number)
select number 
    from generate_series(:start, :end) number
    left join tablename using(number)
    where tablename.number is null
```

Конечно, во всем вариантах по tablename.number должен быть построен индекс.

Вариант с генерацией последовательности на лету силами огромного джойна - к сожалению работает адекватно только на небольших диапазонах. Указанный в вопросе диапазон у меня посчитался за полторы секунды - это только диапазон.

Если есть большая таблица рядом (совершенно любая, лишь бы в ней было достаточно строк), то можно генерировать последовательности с помощью пользовательской переменной:

```
SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS number FROM any_big_table, (select @i:=$start) AS z limit $end - $start
```

Это будет бегать повеселее, но нужна какая-нибудь табличка. Для конечного диапазона, довольно маленького к тому же, всего 1 млн строк - проще заранее создать таблицу с числами.

### За кадром

За кадром остался, вроде бы, только вариант с хранимой процедурой. Можно написать хранимку, которая будет делать именно наивный цикл `for`, но из-за близости к данным делать это более эффективно, чем с приложения. Но один специализированный запрос будет эффективнее, а хранимая логика в mysql - вещь не самая беспроблемная. Весьма неприятен, например, тихий автоматический коммит транзакции при вызове хранимки.

Comment: `И больше её не трогайте, она не для того сделана, чтобы её как-то трогать, кроме как читать.` .......а что, нельзя создать временную таблицу типа MEMORY, в которую запхать значения через декартово объединение таблиц саму на себя......а затем заинсертить их в пункт назначения и хлопнуть временную таблицу? разве не лучше? и не придется хранить эту непонятную таблицу и MEMORY работает со скоростью света

Comment: Вопрос в необходимой периодичности. Временная таблица поможет, если надо сделать несколько операций в пределах одной сессии. Если в сессии только одна такая такая операция - то декартово произведение напрямую будет даже быстрее. Персистентное memory - его надо будет заполнять при старте и всё равно будет болтаться в списке таблиц. А обычная персистентная таблица с лямом интов и займёт всего пару мегабайт места.- грузится быстро элементарным seqscan'ом, потом висит в буфере, пока не вытеснится.

Comment: @Мелкий "Любым возможным способом запишите в неё последовательно числа от 1 до 999999." а если от 000001 до 999999 можно?

Answer (score 2):

В худшем случае у вас 1 000 000 строк в последовательности.
Нужно сгенерировать такое количество строк.

Генерировать их будем с умом. Сначала вычислим сколько нам реально нужно строк. Потом будем перемножать таблички по 10 строк, пока не получим нужное количество.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT start, finish, cnt,
    start+
    COALESCE(a, 0)+
    COALESCE(b, 0)*10+
    COALESCE(c, 0)*100+
    COALESCE(d, 0)*1000+
    COALESCE(e, 0)*10000+
    COALESCE(f, 0)*100000 N
  FROM (SELECT $start start, $finish finish, $finish-$start cnt)T
    LEFT JOIN(
              SELECT 0 a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
      UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    )A ON cnt >= 0
    LEFT JOIN(
              SELECT 0 b UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
      UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    )B ON cnt >= 10
    LEFT JOIN(
              SELECT 0 c UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
      UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    )C ON cnt >= 100
    LEFT JOIN(
              SELECT 0 d UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
      UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    )D ON cnt >= 1000
    LEFT JOIN(
              SELECT 0 e UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
      UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    )E ON cnt >= 10000
    LEFT JOIN(
              SELECT 0 f UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
      UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    )F ON cnt >= 100000
)T
WHERE N <= finish
```

Обратите внимания на условия вида cnt >= 1000.
Оно будет срабатывать(происходить очередное перемножение с табличкой 0..9), только если наше число больше или равно 1000. Т.е. если нам нужно, например 5000 строк. Этот запрос сгенерирует 10000 и отфильтрует лишние 5000, а не миллион!
Это очень важный момент, который сильно повышает производительность.

Таким образом мы получили последовательность с необходимым количеством элементов от $start до $finish.
При этом это будет работать быстро для небольших диапазонов. Т.е. с точки зрания оптимизации всё сделано по уму.

Далее надо вставить в таблицу отсутствующие значения.
Выглядеть это будет например так:

```
INSERT UserTable
SELECT number
FROM(
  SELECT start, finish, cnt,
    start+
    COALESCE(a, 0)+
    COALESCE(b, 0)*10+
    COALESCE(c, 0)*100+
    COALESCE(d, 0)*1000+
    COALESCE(e, 0)*10000+
    COALESCE(f, 0)*100000 N
/*часть запроса я убрал для краткости*/
    )F ON cnt >= 100000
)T
WHERE N <= finish AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT number
  FROM UserTable
)
```

Как делать вставку отсутствующих значений - дело вкуса. В примере EXISTS, может быть NOT IN или LEFT JOIN. Я рассказал как быстро сгенерировать последовательность заведомо неизвестного размера одним запросом в MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

**INSERT IGNORE**

Зачастую при добавление в таблицу, имеющей UNIQUE индекс или PRIMARY KEY, новой строки, очень полезным бывает синтаксис INSERT IGNORE. Использование данного синтаксиса удобно в случае случайного дублирования ключа при вставке, то есть сама вставка не будет произведена, при этом не будет прекращено выполнение.
Обычный алгоритм:

1. проверить наличие строки в таблице по ключу (SELECT)
2. вставить строку в случае отсутствия дублирования ключа (INSERT)

находим объект

```
$row = query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1');
// если такого объекта нет, то вставляем новую запись
if (!$row) {
query('INSERT INTO table …');
}
```

Теперь напишем только один запрос INSERT IGNORE без участия php

```
query('INSERT IGNORE INTO table …') // вставка
```

**Синтаксис оператора INSERT**
http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/insert.html